# rustc does not run after install

Tags: rust-cargo, raspberry-pi4

Using Raspberry PI 4 with Raspbian GNU/Linux ver 11

I installed Rust by : curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh

In command line, I am in "$HOME/.cargo/" folder , and I see  rustc

But rustc –version  gives error : **'rustc': No such file or directory (os error 2)**

ls -all shows execute enabled :
-rwxr-xr-x

Any suggestions?

Comment: is `$HOME/.cargo/` in your `$PATH`?

Comment: I have /home/pi/.cargo/bin  , which is what     source "$HOME/.cargo/env"
suggests to use. 
I added   $HOME/.cargo   but same error.